# Custom Partitioner not working in Oozie Mapreduce action

Tags: mapreduce, oozie, hadoop-partitioning, oozie-workflow, secondary-sort

I have implemented secondary sort in mapreduce and trying to execute it using Oozie (From Hue).

Though I have set the partitioner class in the properties, the partitioner is not being executed. So, I'm not getting output as expected.

The same code runs fine when run using hadoop command.

And here is my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="MyTriplets" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="mapreduce-598d"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="mapreduce-598d">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>/test_1109_3</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>/apps/hive/warehouse/7360_0609_rx/day=06-09-2017/hour=13/quarter=2/,/apps/hive/warehouse/7360_0609_tx/day=06-09-2017/hour=13/quarter=2/,/apps/hive/warehouse/7360_0509_util/day=05-09-2017/hour=16/quarter=1/</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileInputFormat</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                <value>PonRankMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                <value>PonRankReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.value.comparator.class</name>
                <value>PonRankGroupingComparator</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.key.class</name>
                <value>PonRankPair</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.output.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.output.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.partitioner.class</name>
                <value>PonRankPartitioner</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                <value>False</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

When running using hadoop jar command, I set the partitioner class using JobConf.setPartitionerClass API.

Not sure why my partitioner is not executed when running using Oozie. Inspite of adding

```
            <property>
                <name>mapred.partitioner.class</name>
                <value>PonRankPartitioner</value>
            </property>
```

Any What I'm missing when running it from Oozie ??

Comment: Try to give the full classname for this parameter.

Comment: @PreetiKhurana  I'm trying to run oozie from HUE. Even if i give some random class name which isn't available in the JAR for partitioner, no error or exception is thrown. I think the property "mapred.partitioner.class" itself is not being considered. If i change the property to "mapreduce.partitioner.class", the property is being evaluated.

Comment: @PreetiKhurana : Planning to re write the mapreduce code using new API. Since "mapreduce.partitioner.class" property is being recognized and not "mapred.partitioner.class". Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: ohk.. Yes, new property should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by re-writing the mapreduce job using new API's.

The property used in oozie workflow for partitioner was mapreduce.partitioner.class.